# ColdFusion Query Connections

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

When you run a basic ColdFusion query, when does ColdFusion actually log out of the database? When does the query actually close? My understanding is that when you have multiple users being authenticated at the same time, it maintains it's connection and uses a new thread for a new user. But I am struggling to find any documentation as to when it actually closes. Is it when the page is finished rendering or is it directly after the query execution?

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. We are running ColdFusion 9 Standard with SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding it that, by default, ColdFusion won't log out of the database at a particular time. It uses a connection pool, so when you make a query, coldfusion takes a connection from it's pool of connections (creating a connection if none were present), executes the query, then hands the connection back to the pool, ready for more requests. Connections will eventually be closed when they've been inactive for long enough (20 minutes by default, set by the Timeout setting in ColdFusion DataSource admin).

I think the strict answer to your question is: 20 minutes since the last use of that connection, but that's hard to determine

Comment: So if you have more than one user at the same time using that connection, does it use another thread to execute?

Comment: @webNoob - Also, some of these settings are configurable at the datasource level via the ColdFusion administrator.  Have a look under the `Show Advanced Settings` button of your datasource(s).  You can limit the number of connections, enable or disable maintaining of the connection, set the timeout, etc.

Comment: Yeah, we tweaked some of those settings yesterday. We had Maintaining the connection turned on, but after experiencing issues, we turned it off. On very sporadic occasions, Coldfusion is unable to query our SQL Server, and the queries that go through seem to take a very long time. (a page that normally takes a second or two will take times that range in the minutes.)

Comment: I've not used SQL server in some years, but from memory, the connection monitor was pretty good at checking what the connections were doing. It would be worth running that. You can also turn on connection logging at the datasource level in CF administrator, but it's VERY verbose, so use sparingly. If you catch the server while it's slow, you can also run stack traces to see what the threads are up to and see if they are waiting on the database.

Comment: The problem with the connection monitor is when these requests begin to take a long time SQL Server is unresponsive. Then the end users are unable to access our site. It smells like a connection issue between Coldfusion and SQL Server, but I have no way to recreate.

Comment: It might be worth setting up a script from another computer and from the coldfusion server which connects every 30 seconds and runs a simple query. If you have it log the execution time, you  ought to be able to prove whether it's the link between CF and SQL server (where one script would slow but the other would remain fine) or whether it's the SQL server itself (both scripts show slowdowns).